# Should I include a current limiting and reverse current flow protection circuit in a battery charger circuit?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger

I am designing a lead acid battery charger and would like to know the following.

1. **Should I include a current limiting and reverse current flow protection (As shown in the image) circuit to keep the charging current at the required "C" level?**

I've already gone through online resources a bit.

[image]

Comment: By switching low side, you are breaking up the ground in your system. If all you have are two floating batteries, this isn't an issue but I suppose there are things connected to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not only reverse current, but also reverse polarity protection is usually needed. If the charging circuit is a buck converter, for example, the body diode of the buck's main switch (usually an NMOS) will allow current flow to the input side of the charger. Also, when the charger is off you may not want to discharge the battery through some components inside the charger. But you may want to place the blocking switch *(NMOS for low-side, PMOS for high-side, **mind the body diode direction for both**)* depending on whether you require some functionality whilst discharging battery, such as a POWER GOOD output (can be an LED or whatever) or a CHARGING/DISCHARGING indicator.
2. An ordinary power supply can work either CC (constant-current) or CV (constant-voltage) which means either the current or the voltage is regulated (unless the load resistance is exactly CV/CC ratio). A battery charger too can work either CC or CV but it's designed to switch from one mode to another whilst adjusting the limits dynamically. Also, a battery charger employs various protection mechanisms such as over-temperature (both internal and external), over-charging, over-voltage, and more. All of these are for safety and life of the battery. So we can say that a battery charger is an optimised, specialised type of power supply to charge specific type(s) (i.e. chemistry and other properties) of battery safely. <sup>1</sup>
3. Yes. If you have a look at the charging curves of lead acid and li-based batteries, you'll see that the battery should be charged with constant current until the battery voltage reaches a specific level, then the charger should switch to constant voltage whilst reducing the charging current gradually (This usually happens automatically, though). <sup>2</sup> It's also worth to mention the importance of the charging current level: It's theoretically possible to apply the highest possible current to charge the battery. But practically, the chemical reactions inside the battery and the temperature rise will cause either a destruction or a reduction of the lifespan. So there are some rule of thumbs about battery charging current. C/10 is one of the good and well-known levels as it brings acceptable amount of charging time without reducing the lifetime.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> One thing worth to note here is that a power supply having adjustable CC and CV limits (bench-top lab PSUs, for example) can be used to charge Li-based batteries.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> Again, power supplies with adjustable CV/CC limits can be used: If you set the CC level to the charging current (say, C/10); and set the CV level to the max charged battery voltage (say, 14.4V) and connect the leads across the battery (in correct polarity, of course) the power supply will run at CC and the voltage regulation will be lost because the battery voltage will dominate. As the battery voltage approaches the target voltage the PSU will switch to CV and the constant-current regulation will be lost so the charging current will decrease gradually.</sup>

Comment: Okay. But what exactly happens If I connect a power supply with no output current control to a lead acid battery? For calculation let's assume that the battery is 1000Ah  12V and 30% full when connected to the supply, and Say the power supply's max current is 20A and voltage is fixed at 13.8. Does this going to act as a short circuit once connectd connecting? I am trying to understand the importance of current limiting in chargers.

Comment: @Nithin a crude practical battery model consists of an ideal battery and an output resistance (Rs) connected in series. So, when connected as a load across a power supply, the battery will be seen as Rs (very small resistance e.g. 10 mOhms). Now, the importance of current limiting has two parts: PSU/charger side, and battery side. A PSU without current limiting or short protection will quite possible be damaged when tried with battery charging. Also, if you don't limit the charging current the battery will overheat and get destroyed (worst case) or the lifespan will be reduced (best case).